# Mysql REGEXP returns true even though there is no match.

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using the following query

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_widgets uw ON uw.user_id = u.id 
WHERE filters REGEXP '"job_skill":\{"label":"name","val":".*(\[\[3D Designer\]\])'
```

Against this field

```
{"job_skill":{"label":"name","val":"[[Web]]"},"country":{"label":"name","val":"[[Jordan]],[[Syria]]"},"city":{"label":"name","val":""}}
```

This query works very well for my needs, but for some weird reasons, it returns the user_id even though the field obviously doesn't contain this value, it's 3:36 A.M and my brain is almost shutting down, so please excuse me if i am not clear enough.

Comment: try this `WHERE filters REGEXP '"job_skill":\{"label":"name","val":"[^\{\}]*(\[\[3D Designer\]\])'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj thank you, your soultion works, please put it as an answer so i can select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negated character class instead of `.*` because `.*` is greedy which matches many characters as much as possible.

```
WHERE filters REGEXP '"job_skill":\{"label":"name","val":"[^\{\}]*(\[\[3D Designer\]\])'
```

`[^\{\}]*`  matches any character but not of  `{` or `}`, zero or more times.